# Importing data from MySQL to Excel

Tags: mysql, export-to-excel

I have data in excel sheet (CSV format) and I have imported this data into Mysql and filtered the data based on dates (only 2014 and 2015) years have been selected.
The client wants data back in excel. So, I have to import the data which I had extracted based on dates into excel. I believe this would be a temporary table. So, how do we import the temporary tables to excel.

I don't know how to use mysql to excel converter in this case, as the temporary table is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a software by MySQL to handle that

https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

> MySQL for Excel makes the task of getting MySQL data into Excel a very
>   easy one; there are no intermediate CSV files required, only a couple
>   of clicks and data will be imported to Excel. MySQL for Excel supports
>   importing data from tables, views and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this could be as follows

```
select <fieldnames>  
from <temporary table>
```

Then copy and paste the results into excel.    save as excel format, and voila!

Edit:  if you are using a tool like phpMyamin, you can just export the results of your query into the desired format.  If you want the headers, choose "include column names" in the advanced" export.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a document that opens in excel you could export the tables as a CSV file from mysql.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

If you have to actually create an excel worksheet then you would have to use a library based on what programming language you are using to convert the data to an excel spreadsheet.